# Moving a wordpress.org website to another domain name?

Tags: links, hosting, domain, dns

I currently have a wordpress.org website on a server with a specific domain name. I would like to move it all to a server with another domain name as I have changed my company name.

What is the best way of doing this without losing the links (Both internal links and external links going towards the site)? Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution.

First [download this file](https://github.com/veloper/WordPress-Domain-Changer).

Then follow [these steps](http://dan.doezema.com/2010/04/wordpress-domain-change/).

In shortly

1. Backup/download your database.
2. Upload it to your new site.
3. Copy all wordpress folder including wp-admin,wp-content etc from
   your old site to new one.
4. Edit the downloaded php file, change the password. you need to
   change the password in this line. define('DDWPDC_PASSWORD',
   'Replace-This-Password');
5. Now place the downloaded php file in the root directory of your NEW
   site.
6. http://www.yourNewDomain.com/wp-change-domain.php
7. Enter the password you entered in step 4.
8. Now you can see a form filled with your old db values. Just change
   the details. Thats it. You are done.

PS: I have included the screenshot of how value appears in the form

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried to import my sql back up and it said: `Could not import configuration` what did I do wrong?

Comment: Nevermind sorry I used the wrong import tool on phpmyadmin. thanks again.

Comment: It is not working on my website, do you know how I could check the database or if I did any thing badly?

Comment: Hello mate, I hope you have taken backup. That's the first step, remember? If you are using cPanel, you can check your database using phpmyadmin.

Comment: Thanks @Giri but what is cPanel, yes i backed up my database

Comment: check [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel) to know about cPanel.

Answer (score 1):

It's a multi-step process, most of which is detailed here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Here are my bullet points, as I've done it a number of times:

1: Backup everything from the original site. Site files, themes, complete DB dump, everything.

2: Install WP on the new server

3: Upload your backups, specifically /wp-content and your DB backup.

4: Complete a search and replace in the DB for your old domain, inserting your new one everywhere needed.

5: Your new site should now be online. Drink a beer.

6: Once the new site looks good, it's time to kill the old one. Take down everything and set up a redirect with htaccess that will bounce any incoming traffic to the new URL (down to the specific post/page).

I know that's short, but that's the bulk of it. Anything specific you needed to know?

Comment: The search/replace should [handle serialized data](http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/). A [redirect plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) may be useful for step 6.

Comment: Following what @brasofilo said, I use [Deploy Helper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/deploy-helper/).